# Why doesn't this circuit work?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, multiplexer, xilinx, diagram

I want to implement this truth table (in Figure 1.1) into a circuit using an 8-1 multiplexer. I did the circuit schematic (in Figure 1.2) in Xilinx ISE Design Suite and it does work, but when I try to make the wiring diagram (in Figure 1.3) with a program the circuit does not work. Can you help me identify the error?

Thanks.

[image: Truth Table]
                                                      **Truth Table (Figure 1.1)**

[image: Wiring Diagram]
                                                      **Circuit Schematic (Figure 1.2)**

[image: Circuit Schematic]
                                                      
**Wiring Diagram (Figure 1.3)**

Comment: try putting chip pin numbers on your schematic

Comment: Good idea, do you know any good program or way to do this?

Comment: FWIW, and maybe not much, I'd connect D0 and D1 directly to Vcc and GND. That is, if I got it right that they're going to get known values when used, since C controls both them and S0.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The cathode of the LED must be connected to the ground not Vcc

Comment: Wow, good catch!

Comment: I feel so stupid right now, thank you so much, you saved me from hours of pain!

Comment: Spending many hours chasing what turns out to be a trivial screwup is par for the course.......

Comment: Trivial stuff is the easiest to overlook since you usually assume its correct. Thats why those errors hide unless someone else looks over.

Comment: "When a progammer has a hard time finding a bug it's because he's looking in the wrong place". Guess it applies to hardware as well.